# Validation running on all rows when tabbing Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I want a validation to fire after hitting tab on a field. The thing is every time I click on the empty field it runs the validation to all rows. Which causes errors because the other existing rows in the table aren't in the scope of the validation. I am using a back bean function to and can see the validation is called everytime I hit the empty field. I think this has to do with autosubmit being on but how else can I validate on a tab?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this will answer your q's but might be a start:

http://www.slideshare.net/stevendavelaar/18-invaluable-lessons-about-adfjsf-interaction

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/web.1111/b31973/af_validate.htm

https://rohanwalia.blogspot.com/2013/10/client-side-validation-in-adf-faces.html

https://www.jobinesh.com/2009/08/how-to-skip-validation.html

Also, if you're doing ADF work definitely get Jobinesh's book as it covers many things in depth: https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/oracle-adf-real-world-developers-guide-jobinesh-purushothaman/1111982100

Also consider ADF Cookbook.