# In adf When autosubmit ="true" then the entity validation are getting skipped

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

In adf, I have a table in which the autosubmit is set to true for a column. When we change this value it is going through its life cycle and the value is getting update but the entity validations for that row is getting skipped when toggling to the other rows, but when we try to commit it to the DB it is getting validated since the transaction became dirty. Is there any feature which helps it to do the entity validation or anything wrong with my concept.

P.S: It is working fine when autosubmit = "false" i.e entity validation is trigger while toggling between the rows before committing it to the DB.

Comment: this post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67040046/validation-running-on-all-rows-when-tabbing-oracle-adf/67048223#67048223

Answer (score 0):

I believe that usually autoSubmit validation would fire on a navigationevent.  It is hard to know exactly what is wrong without seeing your code, but some things that might resolve your problem include:

1. Ensure the validation is for the attribute being submitted and not for the whole row
2. Ensure you have not set `skipValidation="true"` or altered the phase in another way (ie pageDef)
3. Ensure if you have overridden the default rowNavigationListener that is still triggering validation.
4. Ensure there is no ppr removing your the error message from the validation on row navigation and making it appear as if validation that actually did occur, did not.
5. Try adding `BlockRowNavigationOnError="always"` to your table and see if it still lets you change rows.